Is there an alternative to getChildRelationships from sobject describe in apex?
I have very simple code that iterates DescribeSObjectResult.getChildRelationships() to map ChildRelationship entities to their subselect name.
When I was profiling the code I realized, that this method takes 200-400ms. Completely unacceptable. I am looking for an alternative that does not need to iterate the entirety of child relationships, when I am only looking for the describes of a particular child relationship (e.g. Contacts on Account). The problem is the call to getChildRelationships(), so exiting the loop early on the first match instead of mapping them does not really help.
Is there a way to directly access the child relationship configuration by its name without making slow calls to iterate all relationships? The actual code only needs to translate from the relationship name (Orders) to the child sobject of the relationship (Order). I'd like to avoid rewriting the API of my QueryBuilder from subselect('Orders') to something like subselect('Orders', Schema.Order.SObjectType).

Interestingly enough, a query to RelationshipDomain is possible, but not faster. So this is also not an option (for an OOTB Account object, the query runs between 200 and 300ms for me).
